# How do I stream video from google cloud storage to iOS safari

Tags: html, node.js, iphone, vue.js, google-cloud-storage

I am looking for the common way for people to serve videos through google cloud storage that works on all browsers including I devices.

I am trying to play videos on my web page (Vue front end, node.js back end) that are stored in google cloud storage but I am having trouble having them consistently play on all I devices.

- I have tried the media link ->
  https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/mybucket/o/video.mp4generation=123456789101112&alt=media
- I have tried the public link -> 
  https://storage.googleapis.com/MyBucket/video.mp4
- I have tried signed URL
- i have tried many different options in the tag

  - playsinline
  - controls
- I include the content type 'type="video/mp4"'

Everything seems to work on all popular browsers, except safari, the public link works on safari on MAC, but not I phones.

The public link also seems to work on some versions of I phone / devices such as i phone 7 , I pad mini 2

I have read about accept ranges, that seems to already be set with google storage links as this shows up in the header when inspected.

Example:

```
<video controls playsinline>
  <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/MyBucket/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? running into a similar issue.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found the solution is to set CORS enabled for the bucket as here

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#configure-cors-bucket

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration